# Rate of change of radius of spherical balloon

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, chain-rule

> A spherical balloon is filled with gas at a rate of $4 \text{ cm}^3/\text{s}$. What rate is the radius $r$ changing with respect to the time when the vol $V=36π \text{ cm}^3$?

[ans:$\frac 19, \frac{\pi}{9} $or 9$\pi$]

I tried this one with implicit differentiation:

$\frac{dV}{dt} = \frac {4}{3} \pi \cdot \frac{d}{dt}[r^2]$

- $4 = \frac {4}{3} \pi \cdot 2r \frac{dr}{dt}$

---

Volume formula: $36 π = \frac43 π r^2$

- $r^2= 27$
- $r= \pm 3 \sqrt{3}$

---

Substituting r into the differentiation to find $\frac{dr}{dt}$:

$4 = \frac {4}{3} \pi \cdot 2r \frac{dr}{dt}$

$4 = \frac {4}{3} \pi \cdot 2(3 \sqrt{3}) \frac{dr}{dt}$

$\frac{dr}{dt} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}\pi}$ , which seems wrong. Please can someone tell me where my knowledge gap is?

Comment: In the volume formula is $r^3$, not $r^2$

Comment: darts. nice catch!

Comment: Please don't type the whole question in the title. Use the title to summarise your question and then put the question in the body.

Comment: Ok thanks Toby. The system told me to be as specific as possible.. haha. sorry!

Comment: @nvs0000 This is not an example of implicit differentiation but of chain rule. Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function#Implicit_differentiation and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule. I have edited your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{dV}{dt} = \frac {4}{3} \pi \cdot \frac{d}{dt}[r^3]$

- $4 = \frac {4}{3} \pi \cdot 3r^2 \frac{dr}{dt}$

---

Volume formula: 36 π = 4/3 π r^3

- $r^3= 27$
- $r= 3$

---

Substituting r into the implicit differentiation to find $\frac{dr}{dt}$:

$4 = \frac {4}{3} \pi \cdot 3r^2 \frac{dr}{dt}$

$4 = \frac {4}{3} \pi \cdot 2(9) \frac{dr}{dt}$

$\frac{dr}{dt} = \frac{1}{9\pi}$

Many thanks @alessandro!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Thank you for helping me see!!

Answer (score 1):

Just as another way to approach the calculation, since the volume of the balloon is given, rather than its radius:

You had the result from implicit differentiation,
$$ \frac{dV}{dt} \ \ = \ \ \frac43 \pi \cdot \frac{d}{dt} \ [r^3] \ \  = \ \  \frac43 \pi \cdot 3r^2 · \frac{dr}{dt} \ \  = \ \ 4  \pi  r^2 · \frac{dr}{dt} \ \ . $$

We might wish to have this "related-rates" equation expressed in terms of the current volume of the balloon.  To do this, it will be helpful to find a constant $ \ c \ $ for which
$$ \ c·(4 \pi r^2)^{3/2} \ = \ V \ = \ \frac43 \pi  r^3 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ c  ·  4^{3/2}  ·  \pi^{3/2}  ·  r^3 \ \ = \ \ \frac43 \pi  r^3  $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \ c \ \ = \ \ \frac43 \pi · \frac{1}{4^{3/2}  ·  \pi^{3/2}} \ \ = \  \ \frac{4  ·  \pi}{3 · 4^{3/2}  ·  \pi^{3/2}} \ \ = \  \ \frac{1}{3 · 4^{1/2}  ·  \pi^{1/2}} \ \ = \ \ \frac{1}{6 · \sqrt{\pi}} $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \ \left(\frac{1}{6 · \sqrt{\pi}} \right)·(4 \pi r^2)^{3/2} \ = \ V \ \ \Rightarrow \  \ 4 \pi r^2 \ \ = \ \ (6  ·  \pi^{1/2})^{2/3}· V^{2/3} \ \ = \  \   6^{2/3}  ·  \pi^{1/3} · V^{2/3} \ \ . $$

The related-rates equation becomes
$$ \frac{dV}{dt} \ \ = \ \ 6^{2/3}  ·  \pi^{1/3} · V^{2/3} · \frac{dr}{dt} \ \ , $$

and inserting the given quantities leads us to

$$ 4 \ \ = \ \ 6^{2/3}  ·  \pi^{1/3} · (36 \pi)^{2/3} · \frac{dr}{dt} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \  4 \ \ = \ \ 6^{2/3}  ·  \pi^{1/3} · (6^2)^{2/3} ·  \pi^{2/3} · \frac{dr}{dt} \ \  $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \  4 \ \ = \ \ 6^{2/3}  · (6)^{4/3} ·  \pi^{1/3} ·  \pi^{2/3} · \frac{dr}{dt} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \  4 \ \ = \ \ 6^2  ·  \pi · \frac{dr}{dt} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \  \frac{dr}{dt} \ \ = \ \  \frac{4}{36·\pi} \ \ = \ \ \frac{1}{9·\pi} \ \ . $$

[In calculus classes, instructors are generally not concerned about *units*, but they matter very much to scientists and engineers.  Going back to the earlier equations we used to find the "proportionality constant", we have
$$ \frac{dV}{dt} \ \ = \ \  4  \pi  r^2 · \frac{dr}{dt} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \  \frac{dV/dt}{dr/dt} \ \ = \ \ 4  \pi  r^2 \ \frac{\text{cm}^3\text{/sec}}{\text{cm/sec}} \ \ = \ \ 4  \pi  r^2 \ \text{cm}^2 $$
$$ \ c·  (4 \pi r^2\ \text{cm}^2)^{3/2} \   \ = \ \ V  \ \text{cm}^3  \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ c \ \ = \ \  \frac{1}{6 \sqrt{\pi}} \ \frac{\text{cm}^3}{\text{cm}^3}  \ \text{  or  no  units} \ \ $$
$$ 4 \ \frac{\text{cm}^3}{\text{sec}} \ \ = \ \ (6  \sqrt{\pi} \ \text{no units})^{2/3} · \left(36 \pi \  \text{cm}^3   \right)^{2/3} · \frac{dr}{dt} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \    \frac{dr}{dt} \ \ = \ \  \frac{4 \ \frac{\text{cm}^3}{\text{sec}}}{36 \pi \ \text{cm}^2} \ \ = \ \ \frac{1}{9 \pi} \ \frac{\text{cm}}{\text{sec}}  \ \ . $$
Since $ \ \frac{dr}{dt} \ $ could be thought of as "differential length divided by differential time", we would expect the units to be in cm./sec. ]